# Backbone.js render() never called

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

Simple view (reduced code):

```
My.View = Backbone.View.extend({
  className: 'my-view',
  initialize: function() { },
  render: function() {
    console.log('render');
    return this;
  }
});
```

I use it in another view as subview like this:

```
var myView = new My.View();
this.$el.append(myView.render().$el);
```

First instead of a className the view had a template and the view was rendering fine. 
However when I removed the template and added className instead it is not rendering correctly.

It just renders the div and the correct class name however no logging in the render method is performed. AND when I add some html inside the render method to this.$el it never appears. Any ideas why?

**UPDATE:**

When I put my custom rendering code inside the afterRender method it works. Why is it not possible to overwrite the render method in my case?

Comment: If you want to access `.$el` after calling `.render()` in the same expression, the `render` function needs to `return this;`.

Comment: @PlatinumAzure Sorry missed this, actually in my code it returns this

Comment: @artworkadシ, its working here in the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cyclone009/SyNy2/1/). Are we missing something else ?

Answer (score 0):

```
this.$el.append(myView.render().el);
```

I would render the subview the following way.

```
var myView = new My.View();
this.$el.append(myView.el);
myView.render();
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. The problem is that render() is never called.